# AJAX setTimeout not working when pass through parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, getelementbyid

The user inputs something then using ajax the program outputs something to the user. Which mostly works, the problem is passing variables through parameters to the remote function from my script.

The `setTimeout` call messes up when I pass the text in as a parameter. But when I type it in `setTimeout` function itself, it works:

```
function handleServerResponse(text){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML; //izvlaci se xml sto smo dobili
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = message;
            setTimeout("process(text)", 1000);
        }else{
            alert('Someting went wrong !');
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){ 
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else { 
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("Cant create that object !")
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function process(text){

    //text = 'userInput';

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(text).value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", 'foodstore.php'+"?food="+food,true);

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            handleServerResponse(text);
        };

        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
        setTimeout("process(text)",1000);//cekaj 1s pa probaj opet
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(text){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML; //izvlaci se xml sto smo dobili
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = message;
            setTimeout("process(text)", 1000);
        }else{
            alert('Someting went wrong !');
        }
    }
}

</script>

//*******************************************

<html>
    <body onload = "process('userInput')">
        <h3>The Chuff Bucker</h3>
        Enter the food you would like to order:
        <input type="text" id="userInput" />
        <div id="underInput" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you expect others to read your code, you should at least indent it properly.

Comment: @FelixKling does stackoverflow have an auto-indent function? If not, where can I find an auto-indent function? Because everytime I paste into stackoverflow, the codes goes to the left, and I have to hit space 4 times for everytime to go into the code section.

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your editor then. If you use spaces for indentation it should just work.

Comment: @FelixKling I type the codes straight into my server, and my server don't have auto-indent. What do you use for auto-indent?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch How did you do the identation? I usually use external editor to do it and then copy paste in SO. Does SO has a built in command or tool?

Comment: Paste code into a post, highlight the code and then press ctrl-k. Also, the [edit before mine](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30585910/revisions) by @DigitalDouble fixed your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it is evaluated in global scope. There is no global `text` variable, so the call will fail. Pass a function instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    process(text);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! I also need to pass through the "underInput" and 'foodstore.php', and after editing your changes, I tried to passed through underInput, and it yet again isn't working for some reason. Can you help me with the underinput, and foodstore.php? Just two more parameters? Please?

Comment: You can pass as many arguments as you want: `process(foo, bar, baz)`, as long as your function expects them. If you are not very familiar with functions, I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Yes. I know that. And I just tried to pass in underInput, and I updated all the parameters, so the functions expects them, but yet it doesn't work again. I'm wondering if something else went wrong. Do you mind looking at my code over if I updates it with the new code?

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove "" in

```
setTimeout("process(text)", 1000);
```

[EDITING FOR REFERENCE]
instead like this one

```
setTimeout(function(){
    process(text);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That calls `process` immediately and passes `undefined` to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score -2):

Your AJAX query is needlessly complex.  Are you able to use JQUERY at all?  Its syntax is SUPER simple and its ease of implementation could potentially solve your issue.  Please take a look at this example.

**AJAX SYNTAX FOR JQUERY**

```
var var_one = 'first post item here';
var var2 = $("#id_of_input_field").val(); 
///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'file_to_receive_post_vars.php',
        data: {var_one:var_one, var2:var2},
        success: function( response ){
            alert('yay ajax!');
        }//close succss params
    });//close ajax
///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
```